# What the name of this old horror movie named after the half-woman half-horse creature that appears in it?

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching this horror flick as a kid. but I can't remember the title of the movie my sister says it was named after the half-woman half-horse creature that was in the movie.

I remember the creature being super white and this movie is like 15 yrs old, or  possibly older cause it's like a really old movie like maybe 70's or 80's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Could this be *[The Unnamable](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqmMD4m5fNAhWJx4MKHTfsDX4QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt0096344%2F&usg=AFQjCNEz9leGaubVFYC7KFh7sxxxVKLgUg&sig2=runiuL0bvJznY0RuhUCwzg&bvm=bv.124088155,d.aXo)*?

[image]

This is a movie from the 1980s, specifically the year 1988.

The monster can indeed accurately be  described as "half-woman half-horse" and "very white."

[image]

The movie is named after the Unnamable.

From IMDB:

> Back in the 1800's a lady gives birth to a monster. They decide that
>   the baby is too ugly to name, therefore the monster is known as the
>   "Unnamable". The creature brutally slaughters his family, and gets
>   trapped in a vault. Go ahead to 1998, and some college students have
>   heard the story about the unnamable and want to check out the vault....

This is based on the [HP Lovecraft story of the same name](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/u.aspx) (or lack thereof):

> I was not so seriously hurt, but was covered with welts and contusions
>   of the most bewildering character, including the print of a split
>   hoof. It was plain that Manton knew more than I, but he told nothing
>   to the puzzled and interested physicians till he had learned what our
>   injuries were. Then he said we were the victims of a vicious
>   bull—though the animal was a difficult thing to place and account for.
>
> After the doctors and nurses had left, I whispered an awestruck
>   question:
>   “Good God, Manton, but what was it? Those scars—was it like that?”
>
> And I was too dazed to exult when he whispered back a thing I had half expected—
>
> “No—it wasn’t that way at all. It was everywhere—a gelatin—a slime—yet it had shapes, a thousand shapes of horror beyond all
>   memory. There were eyes—and a blemish. It was the pit—the
>   maelstrom—the ultimate abomination. **Carter, it was the unnamable**!”

Comment: They decide that the baby is too ugly to name, therefore the monster is known as the "Unnamable". Um... but... that's still...

Comment: @GGMG - Be that as it may.

Comment: I remember the movie, and it shows the unnameable having hooves instead of feet.

Comment: OMG thanks guys that's the movie!!! Super excited now